# Dual 4k monitor setup at 60hz with 2015 15" MacBook Pro with Intel Iris Pro over display port

Tags: 4k

Is it possible?

Apple site says it can run two 4k displays. But can it drive them both at 60Hz?

*Upd*. Question was marked as duplicate, but this is not fully correct - 2015 MBP 13 and 15 have different integrated video cards from Intel. And surprisingly 13's card is better than 15's ( 13 - Intel Iris Pro 6100, 15 - Intel Iris Pro 5200).